# didn't got the payload response from the Backend using WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have implement an XML API in the API Manager 4.2.0 but when i try to try out the api in api manager i got a response 200 ok " content-type: text/txt " without the response body and when i try to invoke this api from Postamn ,it works fine.

[image: invoke api from api manager]

[image: invoke api from postman]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [RFC](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text) `text/txt` is not a standard content type. Specifically the subtype `txt`. So I'm assuming it's unable to render the content as it's not able to determine the type.

Comment: the API is XML-RPC i just added the policy "disable-chunking" to the API to work ,but it works only in my pc but when i migrate to production which is kubernetes cluster it return this error

Comment: Which error? You haven't mentioned an error.

Comment: that i got 200 ok without the response object like which appear in postman

Comment: That's not an error, it simply doesn't show the Content as the content type is not known. Try adding the following to your swagger https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/mime-types/ with producer type set to `text/plain` or `text/xml`

Comment: still not working even i added "     content:         application/xml " to the response in the api definition,the problem is that is working fine in AllInOne instance but causes this issue in the kubernetes cluster

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Is the APIM version different? Or anything else that's related?

Comment: it's the same api manager version 4.2.0